# Extending inherited array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance

I have pointer, assume it should be array of class A.
this pointer is defined in Ancesor class, as [2]. it's set in constructor.
the inheritor want to add 2 additional cells to this array, i.e the array shall be [4].

the constructor isn't offer the option to use overrided virtual methods. so, how can I extends the array in inheritor to be 4 instead of 2, without creating the 2 in the ancesor, delete it in inheritor, and create new 4?

BTW, it's not possible to use container such vector etc. it must be array.

Comment: Do any parent constructor allow you to provide the size?

Comment: Can you change the parent class (or does the parent class have any constructor which does not create the array)? If not, this isn't possible.

Comment: I'm not allowed to change the parent class. and the data is in the constructor, I can't modified it.

Comment: Mankarse, I guess you're right. in my current situation, I can't modify it. I thought maybe there's other way I havn't tought about, but it seems not. Thanks to all responders.

Answer (score 1):

If you are setting the size of the array in the constructor, then the simplest solution is simply to overload the constructor.

If you create a new constructor with a parameter being the size of the array, then you can simply call that ancestor constructor from within the derived class' constructor.

In code:

```
Ancestor( unsigned int arraySize ){ array = new OBJECT[arraySize]; }
```

Then use that in the derived.